# Split function in Excel VBA returning odd characters

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

I have a text file containing danish characters

```
"Næsby IF afdeling * Badminton * Sport *"
```

When splitting and placing them in an array the danish characters gets "messed up"

This is the complete Text string in a *.TXT file to be split up in Excel columns:

```
"Ulrich*wiingreen*BenPauWin05 Aps*Søballehøjen 12*5270*Odense N*+4530212215*ulrich@wiingreen.eu*Næsby IF afdeling*Badminton*Sport* *Hal 1*Hal 2*99*11/03/2022 13:00*11/03/2022 17:00*kkkk"
```

The code doing this is:

```
    If InStr(FileName, "forespoerg_") <> 0 Then
        OrderArr = Split(OrderDetails, "*")
        OrderRow = OrdersDB.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1 
                      
        OrdersDB.Cells(OrderRow, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("A4:A9999")) + 1
         OrdersDB.Cells(OrderRow, 2).Value = Date
         For OrderCol = 3 To 20
            OrdersDB.Cells(OrderRow, OrderCol).Value = OrderArr(OrderCol - 3)
         Next OrderCol
    End If
```

The splitting works just fine. Unfortiunately the characters gets messed up.
Example: "Søballehøjen 12" imports as: "SÃ¸ballehÃ¸jen 12"

Can anyone give a hint to solve this character issue.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Please include a [mcve] of your problem in the question and show the code you used to reproduce that issue. • Are you sure that splitting messes up the character or is it already reading the data from the text file?

Comment: I don't see how this code is importing anything from a text file. Please show the relevant code part how the variable `OrderDetails` gets its data. The issue lies in reading the text file not in splitting it. If you do a `Debug.Print OrderDetails` it will very likely show the messed up data already before the split happens. Test it.

Comment: That string you show splits fine into cells on a worksheet, using code similar you yours - content displays as expected.  So there's some other step or detail you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but I suspect encoding mismatch. You can try opening your text file with VS Code and watch at the bottom right what is its encoding.
You can then use `StrConv(yourTextVar, someconversion)` wher `someconversion` is a value like `vbUnicode` or `vbFromUnicode` (see options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function))

How do you import the text file ? If your file is a unix or another non Windows flavour you could try reading the file using an ADODB.Stream, which offers fine control on the encoding. I quickly found a sample [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/107893-read-load-utf-8-text-file-with-vba/).

Comment: Thanks iDevlop
The hint using ADODB.Stream worked as a charm.